# Delete duplicates from list of pairs

Tags: list-manipulation

I'm fairly new to Mathematica, and I've finally stumbled upon something that's beyond my googling powers.

I have a list of pairs, where each pair contains in its first entry a matrix and in its second some information about how it was generated. It looks like this:

[image: Mathematica output of list]

You can review the full list using:

```
list=Uncompress@"1:eJy9nU1y3DYQhTljKvfIAVIlS6dwVVY+Qhau8ioL52C5oJ1YHFlNQt0A+3uY9sIui+\
Y8o8n3A6CH/P2vvz9/+feyLN/WZVn+/Prtny/X5eTfPv08bfm4/f7oHHm8Hf+y7o98/\
fnnsvvt5Z+cR9z+uXPO7rMitODMk+N7AuO7QsTHTy8/++Oj+595PeRgXmhNt3P++/nLq/\
US1PSyCDXtjjAs6oUW9Qb2+sHhoUcP80qL+lLPW/Gcn2/FjtBIUV+H4VZ1f+wpRKU3K6L/\
B1pVRP8Pyq2K6P9BqSik/0prup2Tpf+q1JTRf6VFFej/QIuK6P9AiyrR/\
0G7WZNlNZfC96rD/6isR0+\
cPkC3qIbJNTXkhy86ZsakqEb0c6J6tH4uqmR8Iv89nwpE1eBITe2GPCeqx8Ep/\
PesyldVw6xlP3b/4Jw++yX3h+yX/J+xH9s/Yr9k/4j9M9w/y37N/bPsn+L+\
SfZj7x9U9dGvqsnpzKpun+XQ/yjes6s6HOLdRNWFxO4fnLNLsBHa/\
UQ1HuEdRNV3KvNFUtRIVK1kEdp8Uf01g40Qi+mP3R/RH7u/Qn9x+k/oj+0/OKdPf8n+\
If1xAOD0x/6P6I/9H9NfnPknS2rEx/dpFKmckh5l5i4DbGtqkKKk+\
tHYpYbpGylqtEplxY7QVElFQ+Ts94yqI6km4KSqQW1CST3aBR9ga1M9STXMWv5rc/8s/\
8W5P+E/9n6B/9j8Ef+x+Sv8F92f8F9z/yz/J7h/mv+S/4v7/leKeH7dyMAuEiLe+\
88h9iUu2jO6LKyitxN/EDRQzVs9vhM0UEllx89cn2A+cUxyj24f/MwxSW0x94/xuIL7x+\
RYwf1jrJoZOFwV3zDN/dEob/ctwaSVfXq9bwlmsRpYBqhTA0sCdWpgSQDdt0lI8yx62+\
bXkI5z5PtgDjoBiEFH653OjMe8GVQ1RNtC67WHRuJAhPaSRzYR7TcAcAHgDQBzMZ9GmFgA\
YsznEWatAEh5AAqAlAjkZgDuz7gZYB7k7nK6w5QiQQ/z5qLP/\
aaAOkXQIgFTBC0SMEXAkWCAea41gGF2uDIAFYr7ynwACqrb369zUoGZCajrzv2zaCQVmPt\
n0e4gr6faAgDkE4ek6vrMIYsFAGcCRQBwKFAEQFwpGASuQY8Av6DBGnMfE9f2l/\
UDzFpFwKGAKwLOBFwRxFWCJGTTL3APSHdXZFEKqzYNJB3TnPH48+\
0Duxv4oKYh2vaBP4btApPQtjp976Fx7nue1ZGbpk9gLuTTAJLPtULI5wFkLffFBQLCfXF9\
gHAfB4HDfdn53ziYM5JAZ5vCHaeWBGLMt92ECLNWDaQkwNRASgJMDaQkIHYOvJ8gdm3kzX\
88i3QmlQZ0yaMdyJ4f3xUiyk8MSNZ0O4c/\
MWD2CMOiWhpIQnY0Z3do0ECQLKr4xAA2Qreq+2ODJwZgeuDmgQr6Wwyoor+\
lgDr6WwqooL/5fxn9zf7r6G/+X0F/s/5K+\
pv7o0uZLKu5FL5XHf6ffGLA7AG6RT1OyOdqaufLn9j+I021DBqhzdfU2xF3d1B1/\
1BygqmV4ZGibjek04+5fVZ0o06xf68RazjEWvpj+1+CW/XkIwPq6C8FAER/bP+I/pL9I/\
qr7o/or9l/lv5T7D9Lf+z+B5KfxjRBxWXlzwwQyso7Au6hqoNnBsxU1ZeD/\
baAu6jq4JkBSHVCCTjVHEBkdXlfVJPbCE2TVfzMgDr6Y/\
sXnxlQSH9xAYDQHweAZQH0lwKA/MyAMvrjAIDojwMApr8490+WtOkBmLlO5ZS02f6/\
xwAH2//zJLXHjaYLYJKmWoKN0GZr6v6Yu/8n2n9ED38dt2kGIPS/vjsnXKdu+gDw+\
Pz03x9fLf21uT9/ZEAZ/bH1K/TH5o/oj81for9o/4D+mvtn6T/B/\
ZP0l9xf3Pdf738NDewiIeK9f4Ao7/3PxvSE3CBpYdUGgCTkTlp5AwDHzMi5gZLaHj+\
5J74RKr1xxT6AKjmwQFAlB5YH6uTA4kCZHFgmKJMDCwR1cmCRoFAOLBlUyoGlgxxqekHJz\
AsUNmwsH6OBit6+1IbQSCWzq0jmyaSSEdoyRCOVjNCirwcaEKlkdunYgEgl7VOdMY93/\
0klHbTrEK2M3dToGbupyTN2U4Nn7F5pJRG7V+medNC67F5pJRG7qZUzdlMPZ+\
ym3j1nV59hhhHw3Nf9BVC+uZ8E3U8VwroPNvfvAenufYkT/A5kXFk8wz/\
MiLxD4TCpyQ9mvZ1rSY1+MOs9tctfJwd4bq/\
IAZ7eK3IgzvCJHKzKTcvkYFXuWnnHv0wO8AQfywGe3WM5wOkALQ81u/4VV7LZ+\
geQ6ac4NFv/83S2R5Jm679E3JsGgLmYw3FyMYh4cmr7v0LYmx4AXtjOc9cGXQBlciAu/\
GPIWjnAwUCRg5WWVpCDdcJdm5WDVblrxXaAMjlQV/6JHEjpQOwKeLj/\
pTSwi4SIuwJyiOnVJhsaqOjtRP4egSTaVg/+\
HoHktRtx4lQXAMFU3yNAMNX3CGBe4BaAKu5bEKjivuUAgCi3AKBR3u5bgkkrK79HoE4NLA\
jUqYElgTo1sCSA7tskpHkWLm36chomLm36chomiQNmjU5MeDnYbwkgaMu7c862BBC0C0ET\
BYC/R6BE0A2T21ZW0A2zVgBwHhAEACcCQQCkTKC+\
R6Ag3BmiFrXIGIvVAMcBQQ1wHBDUAMeBQW3PNRUwzA5PBqBYD+\
SmArJA4Lhm1GpjRgLqqr5DIIkmvkNgrrSeaiLgMx/\
8DgEAqb5DoE4A1DyABEALBHIbwT3C1qCNgF9Q/\
g4BHrb4OwTKFEEKBeo7BMoUQVwhSEI2nQQV17LpJKi4lk0nAfHnaA7tLKk3LQQEbSFoJA1\
k23ybtoFps56O3DR9AxVK3vQNlCh50zdQRn5xtwBD1pIfJ4HDFTudPpq2gZJs17QN1GS7p\
m+gTA/EBQKiB9p2AdMDKQyIjQO/\
UUTcOIARceMAQJQfJ4BGuX1wdvPQUgHAhJuHlg2SmB2hPeihg2nhgGCqrQQEU20lwEzBrQ\
RVamDZoEoNLBrUqYFFgzo1sGhQpwaWDOrUwKJBnRpYNqhTA8sGOUz2deMFVlV9mEASTXyY\
QBLt7Wzv55cAjSYBs5w0Gqnkmyym0UglxYcJEDT+\
KgGC5rRkjtHK2E19Xn2YQAW7qb8zdlNnZ+ymns7YTd1cfZhABbupgzN2U+\
9Wtv0WWE9p22+BZZW2/RZaXbQ4ZL4gFDe5OGSYuLZs2w9P7w8zBe+Ql3PNBElpd/\
MW3AgAINVGgDpFwLN7RRHwBF9RBHGOTxSBBgFFEWgcUBSBhgJBEfAMnysCnuBzRcAZYbgu\
5UE2jQAV17JpBKi4lk0jwDypPSqiA6oFhGCg51CFdSlXbM+\
hcknw1Havww6ilBGyq8ZNdwBGxG8WKNMDcfkfQ9bqAQ4Hih5o8YDqgRYQqB6IEQHogZQQk\
B5IAQHpwTEf/A8UxMr9";
```

So for example, the first pair is `{{{1,0},{0,1}},{0,0,0,1}}`, the identity matrix with some info. Now I want to delete pairs where the first element, the matrix, is duplicated. I have Mathematica 10, and thought of using `DeleteDuplicatesBy` and `First`, as in the example given in the description of `DeleteDuplicatesBy`, but was unsure exactly how (typing `DeleteDuplicatesBy[list,First]` doesn't run). Could anybody correct me please?

Also, Mathematica kindly suggested to me that using `First/@list` would give me all the matrices (as opposed to `First[list]` which gives me the first pair). I don't exactly know how this syntax works either, so if somebody could explain that too it would be great.

Comment: `DeleteDuplicatesBy[elms, First]` (`elms` is my simple list of pairs)... and it works. What you mean by "doesn't run"?

Comment: @m0nhawk If I run `DeleteDuplicatesBy[elms, First]` I just get back (as output) `DeleteDuplicatesBy[{{{{1, 0}, {0, 1}}, {0, 0, 0, 1}}, {{{1, 1}, {0, 1}}, {0, 0, 1, 
   1}}, {{{1, 2}, {0, 1}}, {0, 0, 2, 1}}, {{{0, -1}, {1, -1}}, {0, 1, 
   0, 1}}, ..., {3, 
   5, 2, 6}}}, First]`

Comment: Please post data/code as text, not (only) as images.

Comment: @YvesKlett Is there a way to spoiler it? There's quite a bit...

Comment: @user3006690: Use `Compress` on your data and post the **full** result. It should be much shorter. Place a hint to use `Uncompress` on it in your question, also.

Comment: If I build a simple list based on your example, like: `list = {{{{1, 0}, {0, 1}}, {0, 0, 0, 1}}, {{{2, 0}, {0, 2}}, {0, 0, 0,
     2}}, {{{1, 0}, {0, 1}}, {0, 0, 0, 17}}}`, `DeleteDuplicatesBy[list, First]` gives `{{{{1, 0}, {0, 1}}, {0, 0, 0, 1}}, {{{2, 0}, {0, 2}}, {0, 0, 0, 2}}}`, deleting the duplicated third element, which has the same matrix part as the first, but a different "information" part. So: Works for me. What did you do different?

Comment: And for the `/@` part of your question, please review the documentation provided with *Mathematica*: Just select `/@` in a notebook and press F1. Spoiler: This is another form of writing `Map`.

Comment: @user3006690 I have no problem with `DeleteDuplicatesBy[elms, First]`, where the `elms` is an uncompressed data.

Comment: Using the full list you supplied: `list // Length` gives 432, `DeleteDuplicatesBy[list, First] // Length` gives 54. Works as a charm.

Comment: @Jinxed, thanks for the `/@` hint. As for my problem, I copy pasted what you wrote and again the same thing happened - I get `DeleteDuplicatesBy[list,First]` (with list expanded out) as output, as I wrote in an earlier comment. I can post another screenshot if you like

Comment: @user3006690: Please restart your *Mathematica*-session and try again. It works.

Comment: @Jinxed I was just in that process. It worked. Thank you very much for your time, both you and everyone else

Comment: @user3006690: You're welcome!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the compressed list you supplied:

```
list=Uncompress@"<...>";

Length@list
(* 432 *)

Length@(dedup = DeleteDuplicatesBy[list, First])
(* 54 *)
```

Here is the result:

```
dedup=Uncompress@"1:eJytmEFuwzAMBGXZ6D/6ib6ipz6hBwM59ZB+\
324dHUTY3qWsNQPEaBQoI66WpNT375+v+SOl9Jy2x+fj+Tvnq58ew/bHY3unw/hrqHw5T+\
dxewynmW3aec4FGpnZpmWFlgVamfi3vdAqyjigVflDaYnENiRRSZfGlKzy99JeIOSSMs5i\
y6qS9qtgnO1bDUuiASXL+\
OrRZE92KGl2lD3JaEDJvflDaUBJoylKWhZfqyWWapGeZLXEUk2mddSSfWJLtPV6LTGaXEu\
AkokoaSJGKtmmRSrZpoXXErBvZhBFSZZvzJNmEJkGXMI8ubdj1CnIziuMFn4uAbTxlktY7\
2aeHO+7BOwb8+\
R43yUd3dRokadX1k2NJvc3VpXd0ytZp0srK1wUWhZoq3yeVGJbZJoSG6uThQaye38FiKIV\
hUePpsTGencmLjmcS4JoY5Mmx8ay2+2mSmy2P700JTbbn97ercQ2yjR531jvBrcO62+\
yJwHN6iejybUEZMBKXHLob0G0pUmTYwP5VsbbleucO+19A/0tVa+\
6tUShgd5tq3Bd0kkb8Bx6Ez7sm0ID2d3uAeUxCUqCfGtngEKrqXPx1nHo3W99tLrWbloWa\
Kv3fy73HqDEtngZ4NJqbP8TQbe7";
```

If you do not get the same result, please restart *Mathematica* first to get rid of any previous defines you may have made in your session.

Regarding `/@`: Please review the [documentation on `Map`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html).